# Wrong copy command output with postgres

Tags: postgresql, copy

I'm trying to use the copy command to copy the content of a file into a database.
One of the lines have this:

```
CCc1ccc(cc1)C(=O)/N=c\1/n(ccs1)C
```

and when i insert this normally into database there is no errors.

But when i'm trying to use the following command, this line is not insert correctly.

```
cat smile_test.txt | psql -c "copy testzincsmile(smile) from stdout" teste
```

This i what i get (it is wrong):

```
CCc1ccc(cc1)C(=O)/N=c/n(ccs1)C
```

What's wrong here?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

`copy` expects a specific input format and cannot just be used to read random text from a file into a field.

See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).

The specific issue you're hitting is probably a backslash being interpreted as an escape by the default copy in/out format.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to do this:

This is my answer:

```
cat smile_test.txt | sed '1d; s/\\/\\\\/g' | psql -c "copy testzincsmile(smile) from stdout" teste
```

Comment: Well, that's a workaround for this specific issue but not other possible problems, and it's still not really how `copy` should work.